# Programmer mode SugarCRM view.edit stop work

Tags: sugarcrm, sugarbean

SugarCRM 6.5
When I turn off the sugarcrm developers mode, everything I created under custom folder specifically on view.edit file will not work. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://community.sugarcrm.com/sugarcrm/topics/conditionally_hide_button_on_detial_view_not_working_when_developer_mode_is_off?topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Bfilter_by%5D=all) is someone that was struggling with a similar problem. The solution for them was to change from using php validation to using javascript validation. Without knowing what kind of validation you were using though, or seeing the code, it's hard to know for sure.